# Microsoft Expression Blend Preview for Silverlight 5 has expired. What next?

Tags: expression-blend, blend, microsoft-expression

Our version of **Microsoft Expression Blend Preview for Silverlight 5** has expired on 30th June and there are **NO** online license purchase options available.

The following link states that Blend is now an integral part of Visual Studio 2012, but with our current constrained development and release cycle we do not have the option to upgrade our entire enterprise class application to VS 2012.  So, my questions are:

1. Can Blend (Preview for SL 5) licenses be purchased online?  If yes, where?
2. If not, then how can we continue our Blend based development without upgrading to VS 2012?

Comment: chirp chirp...no answers huh? I'm afraid I'm in the same predicament.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about availability of a product from a third-party vendor. The vendor is the one who should be contacted regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Microsoft left us down. 
The only option is to go with Visual Studio 2012, as it includes Blend with it, but bear in mind, it is not smooth, buggy and crashes more than the Preview version for Silverlight 5. 
I've even created a bug report on Microsoft connect, which was deleted strangely by microsoft.

PS : I tested the Update 1, Update 2 and Update 3, all of these on solution containing work done in silverlight 5 and telerik controls. It takes 15 minutes to open, and then crashes, this issues was not detected on Preview Version

For Now, We are changing the system date to a date before June 30, Open Blend Preview, and then fix again the system date (because if you don't, you will have nightmare with Skype and outlook :) )

Comment: We too were using the same option 'changing the system date', but surprisingly it seems to work on a couple of machines and fails on another two.  Now, it appears that those machines require a date earlier than 2010 to get the same working.  VS 2012 hasn't been easy, due to the buggy nature.

Comment: Ok, if this answer was helpful for you please mark it as valid answer. It will probably push Microsoft to work on fixing it